# What are the client libraries to be used with a JMS client connecting to HornetQ/JMS running in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, hornetq

I am trying to following this http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/287-jboss-jms.html?start=1 article to try a simple JMS client with Jboss/HornetQ. The article specifies that i need to add the HornetQ libraries and Jboss client libraries as shown in this diagram:

[image]

I have managed to copy across all the HornetQ libraries but unfortunately the JBOSS_CLIENT libraries is not shown in the diagram (collapsed) so i don't know what are the libraries that are required. Anyone know what are the client libraries if using Jboss 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the only library that is required is location in $JBOSS_HOME/bin/client/jboss-client-7.1.0.Final.jar

The above library covers both HornetQ and Jboss client libraries.